# Switching Videos in AVPlayer Creates Flash When Changing

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation's AVPlayer to play 2 video clips made from 1 longer video (so the end of the first matches the beginning of the second)

When the first video ends and the user taps, I create a new AVPlayer and assign it to my  PlayerView, and start playing the second clip.

This all works, however, there is a **prominent** screen "flicker".

My assumption is that this is caused by the player view removing the first clip and then showing the second clip.

What I need is for this flicker to no appear, so that going between the two clips is seamless.

Do anyone know if there is a way to stop this flickr, either via the AVPlayer* classes, or a way to "fake" it by doing *something* to make it so this isn't visible.

Thanks

Below is the code of my load and play method:

```
- (void)loadAssetFromFile
{
    NSURL *fileURL = nil;

    switch (playingClip)
    {
        case 1:
            fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"wh_3a" withExtension:@"mp4"];
        break;

        case 2:
            fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"wh_3b" withExtension:@"mp4"];
        break;

        case 3:
            fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"wh_3c" withExtension:@"mp4"];
        break;

        case 4:
            fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"wh_3d" withExtension:@"mp4"];
        break;

        default:
            return;
        break;
    }

    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
    NSString *tracksKey = @"tracks";

    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tracksKey] completionHandler:
 ^{
     // The completion block goes here.
     NSError *error = nil;
     AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:tracksKey error:&error];

     if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)
     {
         self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];

         self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
         [playerView setPlayer:player];

         [self.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

         [self play];
     }
     else {
         // Deal with the error appropriately.
         NSLog(@"The asset's tracks were not loaded:\n%@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }
 }];
}
```

Comment: Did you try just setting the background color of the view behind the `AVPlayerLayer` to, say, black instead of white? You're doing the right thing in setting the `playerView` from the old player to the new as opposed to removing/readding it. The player view has to be blank at some point, since you're setting it to the new player instance before that instance is ready to play. You could try only setting the `playerView` over when its `status` is `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`?

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: See the comments for this answer for an actual working impl: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33335884/763355

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to re-create `AVPlayer` for this task. You can just have multiple `AVPlayerItem`s and then switch which one is current via `[AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item]`.

Also, you can observe for when current item has changed with the code below.

```
 static void* CurrentItemObservationContext = &CurrentItemObservationContext;
```

...
After creating a player, register the observer:

```
 [player1 addObserver:self 
                   forKeyPath:kCurrentItemKey 
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:CurrentItemObservationContext];
```

...

```
 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*) path 
                  ofObject:(id)object 
                    change:(NSDictionary*)change 
                   context:(void*)context {
     if (context == CurrentItemObservationContext) {
         AVPlayerItem *item = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
         if (item != (id)[NSNull null]) {
             [player1 play];
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Another thing you can try is creating multiple AVPlayers in multiple Views. Create the views programmatically via alloc and by adding it as subview to main view. Then use hidden or setAlpha property on each view to control which one is visible. This will allow you to also do transitions between players as needed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the flicker issue. Thank you for the attempt at a solution

Comment: Did you try the solution in the comment I posted? The flicker should go away for sure when you have the two players on top of each other, and set alpha to 1/0 depending on which one should be active.

Comment: Please don't create multiple `AVPlayers` at once, there's a hardware limitation of max 4 open on the device as it is and you don't want to make it any worse.

Comment: For a transition you only really need 2, but you should share your solution to make the comment more constructive.

Comment: Using `AVPlayerItem` seems to work on the simulator, but on a device I still see the flash.

Comment: It's not clear how will it actually solve the problem. Why should I put an observer on the player? This observer will work only if AVPlayerItem was replaced. And if it was replaced, this observer wouldn't make any difference, because algorithm of replacements starts and I'll see the flick.

Comment: It's not that you can't have multiple AVPLayers, what you can't have is too many AVPlayerItems associated with AVPlayers as in `player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)`. You can read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933853/4833705 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64485645/4833705

Answer (score 3):

There are two workaround that I found. To me both approaches worked and I prefer the second one.

First, as @Alex Kennberg mentioned, create two set of `AVPlayerLayer` and `AVPlayer`. and switching them when you switch between videos. Be sure to set background color to clear color.

Second, use `UIImageView` as the owner view of `AVPlayerLayer`. Create thumbnail image of a video and set it to the imageview before switching the video. Be sure to set the view mode correctly.

Comment: tried second one, i can see white flicker when swtiching the videos. Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with the video "flashing" and solved it this way in Swift 5.

Set my player variable to this

```
var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: nil)
```

Then inside my playVideo function, I changed this

```
self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: fileURL))
```

to this

```
player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)
```

"fileURL" is the path to video I want to play.

This removed the flash and played the next video seamlessly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise the PlayerItem and seek to zero some time before you assign it to the player.
Then the flickering disappears

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me.

```
 if (layerView1.playerLayer.superlayer) {
        [layerView1.playerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
 }
```

But I am also allocating my own AVPlayerLayer instead of using IB to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Be.The.Water. A couple of questions... What is your layerView1? Is it your main view, your playerView? After you remove this layer what are you doing? Obviously you must be doing something to re-add the layer at some point. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sorry it is a class that has the AVPlayerLayer. You can check it out in apples StitchedStreamPlayer sample codes I believe they call it MyPlayerLayerView. I just have happen to name mine layerView1 since I am using two views with two different AVPlayerLayers in my implementation. Essentially I did a [self.view addSubview:layerView1]; at some point to make sure it was added.

Comment: not to confuse, I also [layerView1.layer addSublayer:layerView1.playerLayer]; to add it back when I swap videos.

Comment: Hi Hursh Prasad, thanks for sharing your tips. 

I'm trying to understand exactly how your code looks like, but it's not that easy to put together the pieces from the answer, and then from the comments. 

Would you be so kind to put together a clear piece of code showing what's needed? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

After too many tries without success, I finally found a solution, not the best one, but works

My entry code bellow, have a look at the **loadVideo** method

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *videos;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger videoIndex;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *player;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.videos = @[@"1.mp4", @"2.mp4", @"3.mp4", @"4.mp4", @"5.mp4", @"6.mp4"];
    self.videoIndex = 0;
    [self loadVideo];
    [self configureGestures:self.view]; //changes video on swipe

}

-(void)prevZoomPanel{
    if(self.videoIndex <= 0){
        NSLog(@"cant go prev");
        return;
    }
    self.videoIndex -= 1;
    [self loadVideo];
}

-(void)nextZoomPanel{
    if(self.videoIndex >= self.videos.count - 1){
        NSLog(@"cant go next");
        return;
    }
    self.videoIndex += 1;
    [self loadVideo];
}

#pragma mark - Load Video
-(void)loadVideo{
    NSURL * bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
    NSURL * file = [NSURL URLWithString:self.videos[self.videoIndex] relativeToURL:bundle];
    NSURL * absoluteFile = [file absoluteURL];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:absoluteFile];

    //*************
    //DO NOT USE '[self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item]', it flashes, instead, initialize the instace again.
    //Why is replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem flashing but playerWithPlayerItem is NOT?
    // if you want to see the diferente, uncomment the code above
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
//    if (self.player == nil) {
//        self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
//    }else{
//        [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
//    }



    //*************
    //create an instance of AVPlayerLayer and add it on self.view
    //afraid of this
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    //*************
    //play the video before remove the old AVPlayerLayer instance, at this time will have 2 sublayers
    [self.player play];


    NSLog(@"sublayers before: %zd", self.view.layer.sublayers.count);


    //*************
    //remove all sublayers after 0.09s, to avoid the flash, 0.08 still flashing.
    //TODO: tested on iPhone X, need to test on slower iPhones to check if the time is enough.
    //Why do I need to wait to remove? Is that safe? What if I swipe a lot too fast, faster than 0.09s ?
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.09 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSArray* sublayers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.view.layer.sublayers];
        NSInteger idx = 0;

        for (CALayer *layer in sublayers) {

            if (idx < self.view.layer.sublayers.count && self.view.layer.sublayers.count > 1) {

                //to avoid memory crash, need to remove all sublayer but keep the top one.
                [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
            }
            idx += 1;
        }

        NSLog(@"sublayers after: %zd", self.view.layer.sublayers.count);
    });



    //*************
    //the code bellow is the same of the above, but with no delay
    //uncomment the code bellow AND comment the code above to test
//    NSArray* sublayers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.view.layer.sublayers];
//    NSInteger idx = 0;
//
//    for (CALayer *layer in sublayers) {
//
//        if (idx < self.view.layer.sublayers.count && self.view.layer.sublayers.count > 1) {
//
//            //to avoid memory crash, need to remove all sublayer but keep the top one.
//            [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
//        }
//        idx += 1;
//    }



    //*************
    //App's memory usage is about 14MB constantly, didn't increase on videos change.
    //TODO: need to test with more than 100 heavy videos.

}




-(void)configureGestures:(UIView *)view{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *right = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userDidSwipeScreen:)];
    right.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    right.delegate = self;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:right];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *left = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userDidSwipeScreen:)];
    left.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    left.delegate = self;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:left];
}

- (void)userDidSwipeScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGestureRecognizer{
    switch (swipeGestureRecognizer.direction) {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft: [self nextZoomPanel];break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:[self prevZoomPanel];break;
        default: break;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I was trying to use this in swift, but for some reason the original layer would be of type `CALayer` which is different from the new layer created, and it crashes after the extra layers are removed. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution (maybe too simple for some people, but for me it worked):
In Interface Builder I **set the background color of my view** (which gets the video layer attached to) **to black**. So it's just 'flashing' black now...

Answer (score 0):

As what [@blancos says in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935373/how-do-i-correctly-use-avplayer-so-it-doesnt-show-white-screen-before-playing-v)

> Firstly, AVPlayer doesn't show any white screen, its your background
> which is white

He's 100% correct because when I set my background to white, the flash was white. But when I set the background to green, the flash was green. So to fix it, I set the background to black

```
view.backgroundColor = .black
```

When switching videos, I used `player.replaceCurrentItem(...)`:

```
playerItem: AVPlayerItem?

func switchVideos(url: URL) {

    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem!)
    // if necessary use the KVO to know when the video is ready to play
}
```