# AVPlayer crashes after multiple playbacks-

Tags: objective-c, ios, avplayer

I'm trying to create an app which plays videos from a file using `AVFoundation`.  The videos are shown in a view accessed by tapping on a row in a parent tableview.  The real app will have a video for each row, but at the moment I'm using just one for testing.

When run on the simulator the app is ok, but when run on the device (under ios 5.1) the video plays ok for about 5 times, then crashes unpredictably in a variety of ways.
Most commonly, the video view loads but the video itself doesn't play, but sometimes
I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on a `coremedia.remote` thread, complaining about objects being allocated with no autorelease pool in place. I've added an `@autoreleasepool` block wrapping the code launching the AVPlayer, but this doesn't seem to help.

I'm wondering whether what is happening is that GCD is creating multiple threads on the main queue to play the items, but they are not terminating.

So the key question is- how do I clear up the superfluous GCD threads the AVPlayer is running on
if the user hits the back button in the video view
As far as possible I've followed the example code provided in Apple's `AVFoundation` documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html)
I've added some logging and (as mentioned above) an `@autoreleasepool` block inside one of the GCD blocks- other than that I haven't changed the code.

The `viewDidLoad` method is as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{   
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TestLapCar2Vid" withExtension:@"m4v"];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
NSString *tracksKey = @"tracks";

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tracksKey] completionHandler:
 ^{
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
     ^{
         @autoreleasepool {
         NSError *error = nil;
             AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:tracksKey error:&error];

             if(status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded){
                 avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
                 [avPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"
                                   options:0  context:&ItemStatusContext];

                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:avPlayerItem];

                 avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
                 [videoView setPlayer:avPlayer];
                 NSLog(@"Asset loaded");
                 [avPlayer play];
             }
             else{
                 NSLog(@"The asset's tracks were not loaded");
             }

         }
     });
 }];
```

}

The `viewWillDisappear` method is:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
NSLog(@"view will disappear called");
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
    ^{
        [avPlayer pause];
        [avPlayerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
        NSLog(@"Race timeline nav controller has %d sub controllers",self.navigationController.childViewControllers.count);
        avPlayerItem = nil;
        avPlayer = nil;
        videoView = nil;
        dataStore = nil;
        pkReader = nil;
        receivedData = nil;
        revDial = nil;
        speedDial = nil;
        mapView = nil;
        throttle = nil;
        NSLog(@"releasing stuff");
    });
```

}

I've been struggling with this for most of today- any help would be gratefully received

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should remove from superview first as it will reduce the retain count by 1 and ARC will take care of the release for your code.

like this

```
[videoView removeFromSuperview];
[self setVideoView:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I've been struggling for more than 1 week on this little bug!!  You saved my days!

Comment: I was having this problem as well. My solution was to make my videoView a weak (or unsafe_unretained) property. My educated guess is that the AVPlayer retains it's layer, so if your videoView is strong you'll have an additional retain. Since the layer is a CALayer, ARC doesn't handle it. Thus, every time you start a new video the old player(s) persist in memory. I could only get to three plays but I was on iPad 1.

Answer (score 5):

May be you leave your videoView retained in some place? Because if you do, your avPlayerItem and avPlayer stay alive and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608570/avplayeritem-fails-with-avstatusfailed-and-error-code-cannot-decode) topic you came up to iOS limitation for "render pipeline" with 4 videos staying in memory.

Remember that setting var to nil does not actually release underlying object. So your

```
videoView = nil;
```

can have zero effect.

Comment: interesting to know about iOS limitation for "render pipeline" with 4 videos staying in memory!

Comment: Where do we need to add this line? I'm adding it at `viewDidLoad` but now it's not showing the video

Comment: @CGR may be when you close you view controller with video?