# AVPlayerLayer and AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I build a Video player in my app with `AVPlayerLayer` and `AVPlayer`.

when a new video is chosen i make this method:

```
//this to remove the current video
    if (avPlayerLayer) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[audioPlayer currentItem]];
            [avPlayerLayer.player pause];
            [avPlayerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
            avPlayerLayer = nil;
    }

//and this is to add a new one
    audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName]];
    avPlayerLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:audioPlayer] retain];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];

    CGRect frame = avPlayerLayer.frame;
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y - 30, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];

    [[self.view layer] addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

    [audioPlayer play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(finishPlayingSong)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                   object:[audioPlayer currentItem]];
    [audioPlayer release];
```

Now, some times when i performed this method the device not start playing the video(it's occurs simultaneity and not on the same video). any idea why it happen? and how can i handle it?

## Edit

I noticed it happen after i play 5 songs.

Comment: why are you using notification , when delegate method's are available for avplayer? try to set audioplayer.delegate = nil along with setting the audioplayer to nil and while initializing new player ,set the delegate to self.

Comment: AVPlayer have delegate methods? are you sure?

Comment: sorry it was my confusion, its AVAudioplayer that has the delegates method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a memory leak. Each time you create an `AVPlayer` with `alloc: init:` and assign it to `audioPlayer`. This gives it a retain count of 1. Then you create an `AVPlayerLayer` which increments its retain count again.

Later, you release the `avPlayerLayer` which decrements the retain count on `audioPlayer` but it never goes back to zero and thus never gets deallocated.

Leaks are bad, but you're running into another problem too. There's an infrastructural limit in iOS to [a maximum of 4 audio/video render pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933853/199163). When you create the fifth one, it's unable to grab a render pipeline, and so playback fails.

To solve your problem, correct the memory leak.

```
audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName]];
```

Using the `playerWithURL:` static factory constructor will implicitly perform an `autorelease:`, decrementing the retain count of that object and avoiding the leak.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason to create new AVPlayer and AVPlayerLayer instances just to change inputs. All you really need is a new AVPlayerItem. Assign it to the current AVPlayer and continue to use your existing AVPlayerLayer.

Answer (score -1):

Generally to customize your MPMovie player it is better to go with AVPlayerLayer with AVPlayer.

By using this customized player you can customize the player controls(play/pause,backward,forward,stop and volume etc.) as you like.