# How to remove AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem properly?

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am getting alert message "Cannot Decode. Decoder required for this media is busy." when trying to play a video file fifth time in application.
After searching I found  [AVPlayerItem fails with AVStatusFailed and error code "Cannot Decode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608570/avplayeritem-fails-with-avstatusfailed-and-error-code-cannot-decode), which says only 4 players canbe initialized in iOS. But I am playing only one player at a time. I am releasing player object and recreating for another play and it displays alert on fifth play.

Comment: hi, have u found a solution for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set to nil your player in viewWillDisappear. or looks for AVQueuePlayer Class Reference.