# Too many AVPlayers causes Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have a vc that has an `AVPlayer` inside of it. From that vc I can push on a different vc with another player inside of it and I can keep pushing on more vcs with a player inside them also. After about the **14th** vc getting pushed on the app crashes with `Terminated due to memory issue`.

When I look at the memory graph (9th icon in left pane) it's at about **70mb** so there isn't an obscene jump in memory. All of my video files are saved to and retrieved from disk and whenever I pop a vc I have a print statement inside `Deinit` that **always runs** so there isn't anything else causing the memory issue. This led me to believe the other SO answers that said that there is a limit to **16** `AVPlayers` at the same time. The reason I think all of these players are causing this memory crash is because once I comment out the player initialization code I can push on **30** vcs with no crashes whatsoever.

I was about to completely remove the player, playerItem, its observers, and player layer from the parent vc in `viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear` and then once the child is popped reinitialize everything again in `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` but then I came across [this blog](https://beckyhansmeyer.com/2017/08/30/too-many-avplayers/) that says

> platform limitation on the number of video “render pipelines” shared
> between apps on the device. It turns out that setting the AVPlayer to
> nil does not free up a playback pipeline and that it is actually the
> association of a playerItem with a player that creates the pipeline in
> the first place

and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933853/4833705) that says

> It is not a limit on the number of instances of AVPlayer, or
> AVPlayerItem. Rather,it is the association of AVPlayerItem with an
> AVPlayer which creates a "render pipeline"

The question is when pushing/popping on a new vc (it will have a player inside of it) do I need to completely remove/readd everything associated with the player or will setting the `AVPlayerItem` to `nil` then reinitializing it again resolve the issue?

If the **render pipeline**s are causing the problem it would seem that the limit isn't on the players but on the playerItems.

code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configurePlayer(with: self.videoUrl)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // only runs when popping back
    if !isMovingToParent {

        // I can either
        let asset = AVAsset(url: selfvideoUrl)
        self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem!)

        // or just reinitialize everything
        configurePlayer(with: self.videoUrl)
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    // would these 2 lines be enough suffice to prevent the issue?
    self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
    self.playerItem = nil

    // or do I also need to nil out everything?
    self.player = nil
    self.avPlayerView.removeFromSuperView()
    self.playerStatusObserver = nil
    self.playerRateObserver = nil
    self.playerTimeControlStatusObserver = nil
}


func configurePlayer(with videoUrl: URL) {

    let asset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
    self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

    self.player = AVPlayer()
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    self.player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
    self.playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = TimeInterval(1.0)

    view.addSubview(avPlayerView) // this is just a view with a CALayer for the playerLayer
    self.playerLayer?.frame = avPlayerView.bounds
    self.avPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
    self.avPlayerView.playerLayer = playerLayer

    self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem!)

    // add endTimeNotification

    setNSKeyValueObservers()
}

func setNSKeyValueObservers() {

    self.playerStatusObserver = player?.observe(\.currentItem?.status, options: [.new, .old]) {
        [weak self] (player, change) in ... }

    self.playerRateObserver = player?.observe(\.rate, options:  [.new, .old], changeHandler: { 
        [weak self](player, change) in ... }

    self.playerTimeControlStatusObserver = player?.observe(\.timeControlStatus, options: [.new, .old]) {
        [weak self](player, change) in ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested it and setting this to nil and reinitializing it is what allowed me to push on 30 vcs each with an `AVPlayer` inside of each one without any crashes whatsoever.

```
player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
```

So the issue isn't the total amount of `AVPlayers`, it's like [this guy said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933853/4833705), `the association of AVPlayerItem with an AVPlayer which creates a "render pipeline` and too many of them at the same time is what causes the problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configurePlayer(with: self.videoUrl)
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let playerItem = playerItem {
        self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    self.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
}
```