# SwiftUI video player control panel ceases to be displayed

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use SwiftUI to create an album in which you can scroll through the video. Faced the problem if the video array players: [AVPlayer] is  large (count somewhere > 5), then problems begin with the player control panel, which ceases to be displayed

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var players: [AVPlayer] = [
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4")!),
        
    ]

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0..<players.count, id: \.self) { i in
                    VideoPlayer(player: players[i])
                        .frame(width: 400, height: 300, alignment: .center)
                        .clipped()
                        .onAppear() {
                            // Start the player going, otherwise controls don't appear
                            players[i].play()
                        }
                        .onDisappear() {
                            // Stop the player when the view disappears
                            players[i].pause()
                        }
//                .tag(UUID())

            }
        }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .interactive))

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a simulator issue. I tested on the physical device and everything was fine.

Comment: I recall reading in the documentation that there is a limited number of instances of AVPlayer that can be active at the same time. The number is not available through an API call or something like that but if you exceed that number, playback fails silently. The number depends on the device (and, probably, on other factors such as whether other apps are using active instances of AVPlayer, say, in a picture-in-picture playback scenario). Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474480/how-many-avplayers-are-allowed-to-be-created-at-the-same-time

Comment: @Baglan - looks like you're right. But I don’t know how can to scroll through the list of videos and play them in this case by swiftui (((((

Comment: @ОлегМосейко One possibility would be to select one "central" video (that can be done with `GeometryReader` and preferences) and only play only that video. I think Apple uses that approach in the AppStore app. It would be nice to, at least show a frame of a video when scrolling, fortunately, that doesn't require an `AVPlayer` and can be done with an `AVAssetImageGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIViewControllerRepresentable

---

```
struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var player: AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        //playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
       playerViewController.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        player.play()
        return playerViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

UASGE:

```
 LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemRows,
                   spacing: 3
         ){
             ForEach(videoList, id: \.self) { player in
               

                   VideoPlayerView(player: player)
                    .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                    .onAppear {
                        player.play()
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        player.pause()
                    }
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this example will also create 10 players, which will lead to the same problem

Comment: hımmmm I think swiftui power is not enough for this, Please update if you find anything